# Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed laravel excel import

Tags: php, excel, laravel

i am trying to import an excel using laravel excel package and trying to use the queue feature for that like below :

```
 $import = new OrderFileImport($request->all());
 $import->Sheets('Sheet1');
 Excel::queueImport($import,$request->file('file'));
 return redirect()->back();
```

and then in my `FirstSheetImport` i am doing like below :

```
class FirstSheetImport implements ToModel,WithStartRow,WithChunkReading,ShouldQueue
{
    private $request;
    public function __construct(array $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    /**
    * @param array $row
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
 
        return new Order([
            'id' => (string) Str::orderedUuid(),
            'shop_id' => 6696,
           
        ]);
    }
    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
     return 100;
    }
    public function batchSize(): int
    {
     return 100;
    }
}
```

but when i send the request i get the error below :

```
Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed
```

i read over the net that its because i dont upload the file and sending it to job is not possible , but i saw it in `storage/framework/laravel-excel` its generating the temp files there .
thanks in advance

## UPDATE 1

i have changed my controller to upload the file first and then pass it to `queueimport` like below :

```
 $import = new OrderFileImport($request->all());
        $fileName = uniqid().'.xlsx';
        $request->file('file')->move(storage_path('/excels'),$fileName);
        $import->Sheets('Sheet1');
       Excel::queueImport($import,storage_path('excels/'.$fileName));
       return redirect()->back();
```

but yet again the i got the same error :

```
Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html#explicit-queued-imports ? It states to use an `Importable` trait. I suppose it adds functionality to hydrate such model properly. Im not sure if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$request` object contains an uploaded file, which cannot be serialized and should not be serialized. You cant pass that whole object to the Job, you have to pick out the components you need.

So instead, you should be passing a filepath to the file, such that the job can retrieve the file on its own instead of trying to pass it as an argument. Every argument you pass to a Job has to be serializable (like Eloquent models) since at one point it has be hydrated from the database.

Comment: i have updated my question take a look please . i uploaded the file and gave it to queue but yet the same problem